# Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to concatenate column values from multiple rows

Table A

```
FName LName amount Id
---------------------
  A    B     100    1
  A    B     200    2
  A    C     400    3
  A    B     300    4
```

I need the result like :

```
FName LName totalAmount count Id
------------------------------------
  A    B      600        3     1,2,4
  A    C      400        1     3
```

How to get it?

Please help me....

Thanks & Regards

Vineetha..

Comment: What have **you tried** so far??

Answer (score 1):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE_A TABLE 
     (FName VARCHAR(10), LName VARCHAR(10), amount INT, Id INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE_A VALUES
('A','B',100,1),
('A','B',200,2),
('A','C',400,3),
('A','B',300,4)
```

### Query

```
SELECT A.FName 
      ,A.LName 
      ,SUM(A.amount) AS totalAmount 
      ,COUNT(*)    AS [COUNT] 
      ,STUFF((
              SELECT ',' + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(10))
              FROM @TABLE_A
              WHERE FName = A.FName AND LName = A.LName
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS ID
FROM @TABLE_A A
GROUP BY A.FName 
        ,A.LName
```

### Result

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ FName ║ LName ║ totalAmount ║ COUNT ║    ID    ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ A     ║ B     ║         600 ║     3 ║  1,2,4   ║
║ A     ║ C     ║         400 ║     1 ║  3       ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38209)

Comment: You are a life saver!! I was terribly looking for a solution for my issue and your answer works for me....Thank you Ali. :)